# JSON to API.AI or Wit.AI

Tags: json, nlp, dialogflow-es, wit.ai

I have a decision tree in JSON.

Right now, I am using that JSON tree in the flow in my website.

The tree has a structure similar to below

`{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Select the vehicle type",
    "children": [{
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Show the Cars",
        "parent": "1",
        "children": [{
            "id": 3,
            "name": "BMW",
            "parent": 2
        }]
    }]
}`

Now, I want to use the tree and convert to Natural Language Processing flow using **API.AI** or **Wit.AI**.

How can I do that? Is there a tool to do that? Or the only way is to manually  create again the flow?

Answer (score 0):

[API.AI](https://api.ai) (and wit.ai) process natural language.  You'll have to convert your query into natural language before using API.AI.  After you do you can use the /query endpoint to sent the natural language to API.AI: https://api.ai/docs/reference/agent/query